# Getting a link to work over text in php

Tags: php, hyperlink, inline

I am trying to set text to be a link in php, however, it doesn't seem to be doing what I want. I am a newb in php though, so I could be doing it wrong.
The code that I've tried (which seems to be the general census on what to do...) was:

```
<?php if (get_theme_mod('second_author_desc','') != '') { ?>
                    <li class="wow fadeInRight" data-wow-duration="2s">
                        <img src="<?php if (get_theme_mod('second_author_image','') != '') { ?><?php echo get_theme_mod('second_author_image',''); } else { echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/images/testimonial-image.png <?php } ?>" onMouseOver="javascript: this.title='';" title="<a class='arrow'></a>
                        <?php echo get_theme_mod('second_author_desc',''); ?>
                        <p><a class='testimonial'><?php echo get_theme_mod('second_author_name','') ; ?></a></p>">
                    </li>
                <?php } else { ?>
                <li class="wow fadeInRight" data-wow-duration="2s">
                            <img src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/images/testimonial-image.png" onMouseOver="javascript: this.title='';" title="<a class='arrow'></a>Follow mutual weirdness on Pinterest for the latest on mental health, making money online, blogging tips, and more!<p><a class='testimonial' >@mwgleason23</a>"</p>
```

where

is starting it in a new paragraph, class is calling the css style, href is telling it to link, the address to link to, and the text that I want hyperlinked.

```
<a class="testimonial">@mwgleason23</a>
```

This is what shows up when I right click on the site and point to Inspect (using Chrome). I'm not sure where else to find source information...

Any assistance would be WONDERFUL! And if there is extra coding you need to help me out, just let me know and I'll share whatever you need!

Thanks!

P.S. For those thinking I haven't tried taking care of this myself, I have spent HOURS scouring the internet for an answer, tried everything I came across, and just ended up messing things up more. Hence why I'm here, as a 1-rep newb. Just FYI.

Comment: Do you mean something like this `<?php
$mwgleason23 = 'Follow me';
?>
<p><a class='testimonial' href="<?php echo "http://pinterest.com/mwgleason23"; ?>"><?php echo $mwgleason23; ?></a></p>`

Comment: <img src="http://mutualweirdnessgleason.com/wp-content/themes/novellite/images/testimonial-image.png" onmouseover="javascript: this.title='';" title="<a class='arrow'></a>Follow mutual weirdness on Pinterest for the latest on mental health, making money online, blogging tips, and more!<p><a class='testimonial' >@mwgleason23</a>" <="" p="">
Here's what shows when I inspect the element. @AD7six

Comment: And @AD7six, I am working with a premade theme that is has .php files. I recognize most of the HTML in it, but the php aspect is throwing me off

Comment: Well, that's html junk and isn't generated by the code in the question. You need to look at what you are producing, not what the browser interprets it as. also, please edit the question with new info, do not write comments.

Comment: @KonstantinosTsourdinis
That doesn't do the trick either... :(
If you have any thoughts regarding other areas of code that may be preventing it from be able to link up, I'm all ears! If you need more code snippets, I'd be more than happy to provide!

Comment: @AD7six
It is calling for user-inputted information but I wanted to skip that and put in my own information so I could add a link to the name

Comment: @maxx223 now you only need to look at, and put in the question, the rendered html source. You are not generating this `<="" p="">`. Again: please **do not write comments, edit the question**..

Comment: @AD7six I've added what I *believe* to be what you're asking for. If not, let me know where to find it and I'll change it for you.

Comment: I'm  asking you to view the source of the page (e.g. open this in your browser view-source:stackoverflow.com/questions/38429121/getting-a-link-to-work-over-text-in-php ), not inspect the post-render result which depending on how bad the markup is can be significantly different. What do you expect this to do? `<img src="..." onMouseOver="javascript: this.title='';" title="<a class='arrow'></a>` - please do not answer me, think about it - you're trying to put a link in the attribute of another html tag - at best that simply won't work. Good luck.

Comment: @AD7six
The point is *I have no idea* what I expect that to do. I did not write that. As I stated above, this is a pre-made theme that I am wanting to tweak for my brand. One thing I would like it to do is link to my social media accounts in this particular section. If it was an easy fix, I would have found an answer somewhere online and fixed it myself. Again, hence why I'm here. There's nothing for me to *think about* because I simply do not know. That's why I'm asking for help.

Answer (score 0):

your code close the href midway

```
<p><a class='testimonial' href="<?php echo 'http://pinterest.com/mwgleason23'; ?>">@mwgleason23</a></p>
```

try this. the link should work. your doulbe quote `""` in echo close the href tag early thus making the link not working so use single quote instead for the php echo statement.

Comment: I had to switch around the last 2 single/double quotes you had in order for it to not somehow mess up my one-page home page.
It still isn't linking though. Is it possible there is something else somewhere that is causing it to not link up?

Comment: @maxx223 sorry i mess up the last double/single quote. i fix it. did u do it this way? it should work if nothing else is messing with it and if something else does then i have no way of telling since that is the only piece of code you show.

Comment: it doesn't work. It keeps it in the right place, but doesn't link. What else could be messing with it so I can send the code? I didn't find anything I thought would mess with it in the CSS sheet, and it looks like everything else in the php for this section is calling on different things...if you have any other thoughts on where to look, let me know!